# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una fila en columnas Ordenadas y con condiciones mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Deseo convertir una fila en columnas ordenadas incorporando una condición.

Esta es mi tabla: wpuk_usermeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el código así:

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wpuk_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key IN ('TeamName' 'tag' 'Player01' 'Player02'  'Player03' 'Player04') 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY user_id ASC
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo Tener como resultado: "que muestre sólo los aprobados"
y que las columnas estén ordenadas no juntas.

```
RANGERS    RS  Jolito  relito  ilodt   huskd
LEONES     LS  lolito  colito  boodt   usskd
```

Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es utilizar una subquery con `CASE` para transponer las filas en columnas, y luego en la query principal filtrar aquellas filas que tenga `status = 'aprobado'`.

```
SELECT TeamName, tag, Player01, Player02, Player03, Player04
FROM (
      SELECT 
         user_id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'TeamName' THEN meta_value END) AS TeamName,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'tag' THEN meta_value END) AS tag,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player01' THEN meta_value END) AS Player01,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player02' THEN meta_value END) AS Player02,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player03' THEN meta_value END) AS Player03,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player04' THEN meta_value END) AS Player04,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'status' THEN meta_value END) AS status
      FROM wpuk_usermeta
      GROUP BY user_id) AS sq
WHERE status = 'aprobado';
```

Comment: MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'TeamName' THEN meta_value END) AS TeamName, MAX(CAS...' at line 1

Comment: ¿Que versión de MariaDB estás utilizando?

Comment: Operating System: Linux 
Server Info: LiteSpeed 
PHP Version: 7.2.34 
PHP Post Max Size: 20 GB 
PHP Time Limit: 1440 
MySQL Version: 5.5.5 
Max Upload Size: 20 GB 
Multibyte String: Installed 
Libxml extension: Installed - Version: 2.9.7 
PDO extension: Installed - PDO Drivers: mysql, sqlite 
Zip extension: Installed 
Curl extension: Installed - Version: 7.77.0

Comment: [Aquí lo puedes probar con datos de ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=687fc2ce40c8dc8aac4c0cfe1ceda6a2). Puedes cambiar la versión del RDBMS también.

Comment: No veo nada en la sintaxis que pueda fallar. ¿Has copiado tal cual la query sin modificarla? Revisa que los nombres de columna, el de la tabla y los valores de meta_key sean correctos.

Comment: Genio!! Gracias

Comment: De nada @SlaJ!!!